# perform 301 redirects from one server to another

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have some blog posts that are being hosted on hubspot under a subdomain: blog.domain.com

I'm moving my main site under my main domain (a wordpress site being hosted under a wp specific hosting). 
So I will be combining the blog content to domain.com

But the problem is that since I won't be using the hubspot hosting, I shouldn't be doing any redirection over there.

Is it possible to perform 301 redirects on my main hosting to get traffic from hubspot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Configure the redirects from WordPress:**

You have two options here:

- Using a plugin. Take a look at [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/).
- Editing the `.htaccess` file yourself.

  If you are moving your blog from `foo.bar.com` to your web root, `bar.com`, you need to add this at the top of your `.htaccess`:

  ```
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo\.bar\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://bar.com/$1 [R=301,L]
  ```

  If you want to use a subdirectory instead, then:

  ```
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo\.bar\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://bar.com/foo/$1 [R=301,L]
  ```

  The meaning of the flags is:

  - [`NC`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc): Case insensitive, mainly for old browsers or utilities such as `wget` or `curl`, as modern browsers will convert domain names to lowercase.
  - [`L`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l): Stop processing rules after this one.
  - [`R=301`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r): Responds with a `301 Moved Permanently`. Note if you just use `R`, it will send a `302 Found`.

**Configure the redirects from HubSpot:**

As you don't want to keep HubSpot, this won't work for you, but I will leave it here as a reference for others.

There's plenty of information on how to configure redirects form HubSpot in the official documentation: https://knowledge.hubspot.com/website-user-guide/how-to-use-the-url-mapping-tool-to-redirect-pages

> The COS URL Mappings tool can redirect any primary COS domain connected in Content Settings > Domain Manager. It cannot redirect domains associated with external sites. Your destination URL, however, can be any URL you want (whether or not you own the domain is irrelevant).

You need to use the **COS URL Mappings** tool. Particularly, you need to use patterns URLs:

[image]

Comment: I'm aware of this tool. But I'm planning to retire my hubspot account that means i shouldn't be doing the redirection there?

Comment: @PatrickC See the edited answer, I would go for the `.htaccess` solution.

Comment: My main site is on wpengine while the current blog page is on hubspot. Can I use the .htaccess file on my wpengine server to redirect traffic from the hubspot to wpengine using your apache code?

Comment: @PatrickC I have never used `wpengine`, but from the official support pages [here](https://wpengine.com/support/htaccess/) it looks like they do support `.htaccess`, offer their own [redirect tool](https://wpengine.com/support/redirect/) and, for bulk redirects, also allow you to send the `.htaccess` rules and they will create the redirects for you. Maybe it's better that you contact them directly and ask for the best way to do this in their platform.